# Encountering permission errors when running NEW Python scripts from my Terminal? OS X

Tags: python, bash, macos, terminal, permissions

I've been creating a Python script for web crawling, but in the past week I've developed a bizarre problem creating new files. Every time I create a new file, for example, `test.py` and try to run it from the Terminal I get an error:

```
-bash: ./test.py: Permission denied
```

If I duplicate a file that I've already been using, there's no issue. But if I create a new file and copy and paste code from an old file to the new one, OR if I try and write new code from scratch, I get the same error.

I've included a screenshot of what the beginning of my code looks like for one particular script. The left side works. The right side does not.

I'm using Python 2.7.1

[image: Example]

Comment: A screenshot showing how `chmod +x ./test.py; ./test.py` fails and `cp test.py other.py; chmod +x ./other.py; ./other.py` succeeds would be a lot more useful. Assuming you have the `chmod` part covered already, I would suspect something with your editor, but you are not revealing what you use for editing.

Comment: @tripleee I didn't set the permissions correctly. I'm using Brackets as a text editor, but this is my first attempt using Python and scripting, so I'm new to some of the basics. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the execute permission bit on the file? Run: `chmod +x my_file.py` to add that permission.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I ran "chmod +x test.py" and it worked! Thank you so much! I'm still pretty new to scripting, thank you for your help!